# How do you generate keys for Authenticode signing?

Tags: public-key-encryption, authenticode

How does one generate the original public/private keys used for Authenticode signing? I see commans like this in the tutorials:

```
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk mykey.pvk -pi <password> -spc mycert.spc -pfx mycert.pfx -po <password>
```

but they don't say how to get the private key in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a Twitter answer, "You need to get a Class 3 Code Signing cert from a CA."

Answer (score 1):

For testing you can generate a self sign certificate:

```
REM May change depending of your installed Windows SDK
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin"

REM Generate the root certificate
.\makecert.exe -r -pe -n "CN=Sample.CA" -ss CA -sr CurrentUser -a sha1 -cy authority -sky signature -sv d:\Sample.CA.pvk d:\Sample.CA.cer

REM Add the Root certificate to the user store
certutil.exe -user -addstore Root d:\Sample.CA.cer

REM Create the certificate for code signing
.\makecert.exe -pe -n "CN=Sample.CodeSigning" -eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" -a sha1 -cy end -sky signature -ic d:\Sample.CA.cer -iv d:\Sample.CA.pvk -sv d:\Sample.CodeSigning.pvk d:\Sample.CodeSigning.cer

REM Convert to certificate to pfx file format
.\pvk2pfx.exe -pvk d:\Sample.CodeSigning.pvk -spc d:\Sample.CodeSigning.cer -pfx d:\Sample.CodeSigning.pfx
```